# How to Manage FIFO rule for reducing stock in a Point of Sale

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

How to manage FIFO rule for reducing the stock after selling of their items.

The requirement is that when an item is sold in a large quantity let say 10000 units then system should reduce the stock according FIFO rule.

Now i explain in detail.

In below example when 10000 units of a same item are sold and system has 12000 units available in stock but these 12000 units were purchased in four different creditors at different stock i.e.

- in 1st purchase 3000 units
- in 2nd purchase 3000 units
- in 3rd purchase 3000 units
- in 4th purchase 3000 units

now when 10000 units are going to be sold i want that system should reduce the stock of these 10000 units of the item as following

- 3000 units (from 1st purchase) Current Stock will be 0 units
- 3000 units (from 2nd purchase) Current Stock will be 0 units
- 3000 units (from 3rd purchase) Current Stock will be 0 units
- 1000 units (from 4nd purchase) Current Stock will be 2000 units

how can I manage it?

I am using vb.net and mySQL 5.7 database server.

Comment: This is not a code question yet and the fact that you think it is is part of the problem. You need to spend some time to work out the logic involved first. Only once you know what the code actually has to do, should you consider writing code to do it. What would you do if had to do this all with pen and paper? If you can't explain that then how could you write code to do it? If you can explain it then you can formalise it into an algorithm and then write code to implement that specifically. You haven't actually put enough thought into the problem to have encountered a specific issue yet.

Comment: You need to think about the logic yourself and then do the actual coding yourself. We can solve your specific coding problems for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ordered UPDATE and use user-defined variable.

Demo:

```sql
UPDATE stock
SET sell = CASE WHEN @sell < purchase - sell
                THEN sell + @sell + (@sell := 0)
                ELSE 0 * (@sell := @sell - purchase + sell) + purchase
                END
ORDER BY stock_id;
```

For parametrized query use

```sql
UPDATE stock
SET sell = CASE WHEN @sell < purchase - sell
                THEN sell + @sell + (@sell := 0)
                ELSE 0 * (@sell := @sell - purchase + sell) + purchase
                END
WHERE (@sell := ?)  --   <<- the amount to be sold
ORDER BY stock_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RygDR_Y_)